# How do I find the number of columns that a specific user has right to use in queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm attempting to calculate the number of columns that a specific user has the right to use in queries in PostgreSQL.

To do this, I've explored the `information_schema.column_privileges` table, which contains information about privileges granted on columns.

Here's my current approach:

```
SELECT grantee, COUNT(DISTINCT column_name)
FROM information_schema.column_privileges
WHERE grantee = 'specific_user'
  AND privilege_type = 'SELECT'
GROUP BY grantee;
```

However, I'm not entirely sure if I'm using the right table for this task. It is my assumption that if the privilege_type is `SELECT`, it means that the user can use these columns in queries. I might be wrong, therefore I am looking for a more suitable column or approach provided by PostgreSQL to accurately determine the user's column access privileges.

For reference, here's the [PostgreSQL documentation on the information schema.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/information-schema.html)

Comment: It's possible to use a column in a query without having select privilege on it, eg: `update employee set salary = salary * 1.1` only requires update privilege, but without select they can't see the values.